# docker reverse-proxy doesnt work when change network (by --net)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, docker-network

docker version: 17.05.0-ce

I have some containers running by hand using `docker run ...` but recently for new project I create **docker-compose.yml** file based on [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-reverse-proxy-docker). However when i run following commands in my hosting:

```
docker network create --driver bridge reverse-proxy
docker-compose up
```

and

```
docker run -d --name nginx-reverse-proxy --net reverse-proxy  -p 80:80 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

The proxy not work for old containers and I am unable to use subdomain to that projects (they "stop work").

So what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make experiments with  `--net` parameter in `docker run ...` and using `docker network inspect network_name`. I get many different results like **welcome to nginx** or **http 404 not found** or **http 503 temporarily unavailable** and get following conclusions:

1. if no `--net` command then container is run in *bridge* network
2. if `--net xxx` command then cntainer is run only in 'xxx' network (not in *bridge* !)
3. if `--net xxx --net yyy` then container is run only in 'yyy' (no 'xxx' at all!)

The *bridge* is default docker network for containers inter-communication.

So when on running proxy we use only `--net reverse-proxy` then proxy container not see *bridge* and cannot communicate with other containers. If we try to use `--net reverse-proxy --net bridge` (two or more times in one line - like `-p`) then container will be connected only to last network.

So solution is... run proxy in following way:

```
docker run -d --name nginx-reverse-proxy  -p 80:80 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro jwilder/nginx-proxy
docker network connect reverse-proxy reverse-proxy
```

As you see we not use `--net` command at all. The `network connect` command allow container to connect to use multiple networks. When you execute `docker network inspect reverse-proxy` and `docker network inspect bridge` we will see that nginx-reverse-proxy is in both networks :)